# Calculating priors with large number of classes

Tags: bayesian, naive-bayes

I'm trying to classify users into ~1K different groups. I'm trying to build a MAP classifier and have estimated my prior and posterior distributions using large amounts of data. The issue that I've run into now is that all of my priors are very close to zero (majority < 0.01). I believe that this is due to the large number of classes.

Prior was calculated as (# of users in group) / (total # of users) (adjusted using Laplace smoothing).

Does anyone have any advice on how I can adjust my prior probabilities when facing this issue?

My first thought was to just say "whatever!" and assume a uniform prior, i.e. all groups are equally likely. It doesn't look too bad when I do this but I do feel like the prior probability of each group would be useful if it wasn't so deflated.

Other thoughts are to exclude low frequency groups (i.e. if group only occurs for one user) before building my distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 1000 classes, relatively uniformly distributed, then **the prior probability on each class is close to 0**. MAP estimation isn't affected by the scale of the probabilities; it looks at the argmax.

If you're having trouble identifying so many unique classes, it might be a good idea to aggregate them in some way.

Comment: True! I guess where I am struggling is I do the arg max of prior(true) * posterior(true) and prior(false) * posterior(false) for each class. This is giving me huge false probabilities but I don't think that's right. Am I just missing something here?

Comment: Well, if you pick a random class, then it will have 0.1% probability of being correct and 99.9% probability of being wrong. So on average, your "false" probability will be larger than your "true". What matters is that $\sum_{i=1}^{1000}{prior(x_i)*posterior(x_i)} = 1$.

Comment: Okay, I think I see my error in logic. Thank you for your help!